# msal-angular: how to ask user to login again for important operations on your app?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am using msal-angular to authenticate my angular application against azure active directory. It is working fine.

For some important application operations, e.g. signing a document, the application needs to ask the user to authenticate again for security reasons.

In the msal-angular document, it states:

```
You should ask user to login again for important operations on your app.
```

But I don't know how to do it and can't find any examples.

Comment: Call loginRedirect on the app object you create? :) You might want to also include prompt=login in the extraQueryParameters to force login

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any import operations on your app, don't just add authentication to specific routes like `canActivate : [MsalGuard]`. You need to call `loginPopup()` method again. Here is an [sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-core/samples/VanillaJSTestApp/index_LoginPopup.html) for your reference.

```
  let tokenRequest = {
    scopes: applicationConfig.graphScopes
    // loginHint: "idlab@msidlab4.microsoft.com",
    // extraQueryParameters: "prompt:login"
  };
  userAgentApplication.loginPopup(tokenRequest).then(function (response) {
    //Login Success
    let tokenRequest = {
      scopes: applicationConfig.graphScopes
    };
```